# Use multiple emails in php array

Tags: php, arrays

I am stuck here. Have a php code like this which works fine:

```
$adminMail = array(
    'from'      => $values['email'],
    'replyTo'   => $values['email'],
    'email'     => 'email@myemail.com', //how to add second email address?  
    'subject'   => 'Feedback Message',
    'template'  => false
);
```

how to add secondary email address to 'email' =>

Thanks in advance

Comment: it depends, either concatenate another one on the string, or accept multiple strings in a form of an array like `'email' => array('email1', 'email2'),` and so on

Comment: Dropping with errors  when using this strings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place another email with comma `(,)` separated. like below:

```
$adminMail = array(
    'from'      => $values['email'],
    'replyTo'   => $values['email'],
    'email'     => 'email@myemail.com, second@myemail.com', //how to add second email address?  
    'subject'   => 'Feedback Message',
    'template'  => false
);
```

Comment: code of 7 lines and u said error on line 190... there is not index found in this code with name of required ... @Telepuzik

Comment: added 
$headers .= "BCC:" . "second@email.com\r\n";

Answer (score 0):

```
$adminMail['email'] .= ', ' . $secondEmail;
```

Comment: did not get it... Should I create second $adminMail ?